# Getting error "Invalid command 'echo'..." when restarting apache when trying to use SSLPassPhraseDialog

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, echo

Using a solution to another answer, I added the following to my apache config:

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/path/to/passphrase-script
```

And in that script, I placed this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "put the passphrase here"
```

Now, when I restart apache, i get the following error:

```
Invalid command 'echo', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Should I be using some other command in the shell script? Or do I need to configure apache differently so the echo command works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell (`/bin/sh`) does not appear to support `echo` as a built-in command, and your script is probably being called from an environment that doesn't have a valid `PATH` environment variable set.

Use the full path to the `echo` command (usually `/bin/echo`, sometimes `/usr/bin/echo`) instead and things should work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and the problem was the location of the script. It shouldn't be inside "conf-enabled" folder or anything similar to that - otherwise, Apache will try to run it somewhere during the startup process.